# When inserting a string that include html entities, string is cutted off

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form that similar to one below.

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="header" />
     <textarea id="ck_editor" name="content"></textarea>
   </form>
```

When form sent I replace special characters like `Ğ, Ş, Ü` with their corresponding html entity. Then insert edited string to database with PHP/MySQLI. `content` is inserted without any problem. But when it comes to `header`, it is cutted of after special character's position.

When I want to insert

> Türkçe Karakter

It inserted to table like

> T

I echo out `header, content` variables - without any problem - to notify whether inserting proccess is successel or not. 
MySQL Table

```
icerik_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
icerik_baslik VARCHAR(255) 
icerik_icerik TEXT
icerik_durum INT(11) DEFAULT = '1'
collation utf8_unicode_ci
```

How can I solve this problem?

PHP Code // (icerik = content)  (baslik = header)

```
 if ($_POST) {

    ... 

    if ($ekle == true) {
            // Girdileri Düzenle
            // HTML Entity
            $baslik = htmlentities($baslik, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
            $icerik= htmlentities($icerik, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");


            $ekle_db = $db->query("INSERT INTO icerikler SET
                icerik_baslik = '$baslik',
                icerik_icerik = '$icerik'
            ");

            if ($ekle_db) {
                $ekle_msg[] = "<span style='color: rgba(140,200,30,1)'>İçerik Başarıyla Eklendi:</span> $baslik";
                $ekle = true;
            } else {
                $ekle_msg[] = "<span style='color: red'>İçerik Eklenenemdi.</span>";
                $ekle = false;
            }
        }

        ...
     }
```

Comment: If the problem occurs when you try to insert the string into your database using PHP, then showing the PHP code that you use to do that might be useful as well

Comment: Please show your code. If you're not using parametrized queries, you need to escape your input. Also, what is the collation of the table?

Comment: @MarkBaker and Barmar I edited the question.